# TinyMCE - Pasting from word

Tags: javascript, content-management-system, ms-word, tinymce

I'm trying to configure TinyMCE so that it accepts pasting from Microsoft Word and cleans it up in an expected HTML hierarchy.

Most of our editorial staff use a single line break to denote a line break and a double return to indicate a paragraph. However, MS Word's output puts the next line in a separate paragraph (unless you shift-enter for a carriage return) and a blank paragraph with non-breaking space for two returns. Is there any way to sanitize this input? I've tried playing around with the plugins but can't find any magic combo.

Answer (score 5):

I've had success with [this plugin](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:paste).